# predict the next 6 numbers series based on previous series of 6 numbers(training data) using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

problem based on number of series prediction.
I have given the series of 6 numbers and want to predict next 6 numbers

conditions:
Input at monday - first 6 numbers are in range (1-100)

input at tuesday - first 5 num are in range (1-100) & 6 the num in range(1-15)

Input :

Monday  -  34, 45, 56, 37, 78, 65

Tuesday -  78, 45, 36, 57, 89, 12

Wed -      45, 67, 84, 56, 57, 89

Thu -      65, 45, 67, 85, 49, 10

Fri -      67, 56, 67, 74, 53, 49

Sat -      56, 67, 48,59, 60, 8

Sun -      no any data(holiday)

again the pattern repeats

output :
next series

I think regression would be useful?
but how to proceed as it is not having any labels

required help to make some code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know if series of 5 numbers and one output is given ..then if input is given as 5 numbers and predict the answer ..but in this question no label is given so how to approach it

Comment: Just give me idea how to approach such problems or which algorithms of ml are useful..i am new in machine learning so please understand if anything wrong i asked

Comment: you can do this if it is not independence data.

Comment: Independent in sense ..data of monday should not be dependent with tuesday. Thats what you are saying?

Comment: @yacho cho ,@ green cloak guy ..why the people are downvoting me ..is anything wrong in the question

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
I think you can have a try any RNN framework, as you data is time series. You can try RNN, GRU, LSTM, etc. For each day, you can treat every 3 value as input, the next one will be you label, i.e. output.

```
E.g. [[-34],[45],[56]]   [37]
     [[45],[56],[37]]    [78]
     [[56],[37],[78]]    [65]
     [[-78],[45],[36]]   [57]
     [[45], [36],[57]]   [89]
     ....
```

Of course you can try every two or four as input, next one will be an output, see what is the best. And convert the each of the output as an onehot. What is more, you may give each of the day as one of the input as well. For instance, you give all the Monday input a 1 as the first feature, Tuesday give a two, Wednesday give a 3, and so on. As each day information may help model to find some pattern as well. So the examples going to be

```
[[1],[-34],[45],[56]]   [37]
[[1],[45],[56],[37]]    [78]
[[1],[56],[37],[78]]    [65]
[[2],[-78],[45],[36]]   [57]
[[2],[45], [36],[57]]   [89]
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for helping . I will let you know